# Taking all values from an array in the same command

Tags: javascript

In order to take a specific value from an array element I use this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li[dat*="era"] ul li.title div')[0].textContent
```

if I want to take the next value I have to replace the 0 with 1 etc.

Is it possible to use the same command and take all the values from the array using something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li[dat*="era"] ul li.title div')[0:40].textContent
```

Comment: You need to iterate through the collection returned by `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: @Terry thank you I though if it exists a more let's say simple option.

Comment: @Terry also when I tried to iterate using this `for (i = 0; i < document.querySelector('li[dat*="era"]').length; ++i) {
  document.querySelectorAll('li[dat*="era"] ul li.title div')[i].textContent
}` it give me back this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined  at <anonymous>:2:64` it works only when I use a single value

Comment: @Astetr please think of [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array.map()` function:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li[dat*="era"] ul li.title div').map(x => x.textContent);
```

**EDIT**

If your environment does not support arrow functions, you can use map with a plain function too:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li[dat*="era"] ul li.title div').map(function(x) {
    return x.textContent
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=control)

> The Array.from() method creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.

with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control)

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li[dat*="era"] ul li.title div')).forEach(function (currentValue, index, array) {
    // your code
});
```